# Placing <video> controls at the top of the video

Tags: html, video, controls

I am trying to display video controls at the top of a video that I am putting on my company's website, but I haven't found anything on google (or stackoverflow directly) in order to get this to work right.  Basically, anything I try keeps the controls at the bottom of the video (which I assume is the default).

```
 <video class="yadda" width="100%" controls="top">....</video>
```

does not work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: *gives hug* :) So what exactly isn't working with it? Is it not showing up?

Comment: The controls stay at the bottom of the video.  I just want it to go at the top.  I'll edit so it clarifies that, I'm sorry for not putting it right.

Comment: Don't worry about it! We are here to help you out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `controls` attribute takes no values- it should be used like this instead:

```
<video class="yadda" width="100%" controls>....</video>
```

The controls will appear on the bottom of the video, with standard icons. Unfortunately, the video controls are also not customizable. If you want them at the top, you will have to create your own custom interface.

Information from http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080122/#controls

Comment: I see.  I never came across anything that actually specified that.  I know controls appear without putting anything to it, but I have seen
     controls="none"
which I suppose is just like not having controls typed there at all, so I assumed there was some way I didn't know.

Thanks so much for this answer!

Comment: @papaner Yup, no problem!

Comment: Thanks so much for that!  I actually haven't come across w3 in any searches.  It's a lot of good knowledge!

Comment: @papaner For sure! They make the standard, after all :)

Answer (score 0):

According to this Chrome bug, the media controls are accessible from Javascript.  Unfortunately, access seems to be browser specific.

https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=86769

Hopefully, these controls will be made accessible via standard methods.  I don't want to write my own or use 3rd party media controls when they're already in every HTML5 compliant browser and are being visually manipulated.